# Can not add automatic numbers behind with php

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have the code from the database, the data should appear automatically in sequence. the code is composed of text and number like this `CO-00001` but when I generate the code it just adds one digit in the back but not add the value of example `CO-00001 to CO-000001` how to solve it?

ex :

```
    $id = 0902340
    $query = "SELECT substr(code_id,3,5) as cd  FROM tb_inv WHERE substr(code_id,3,5) =  '".$id."' ORDER BY code_id DESC LIMIT 1";
    $get_id =  $this->db->query($query);
    $show_id = $get_id->num_rows();
    $new_code = $get_id->row();

    if($show_id > 0){
        $new = $new_code->cd + 1;   
        $fix_code = $new;
    }else{
        $fix_code = 'CO-00001';
    }
```

Comment: Your code seems to have some falws. First you have initialized `$id = 0902340`. This number is not a valid number because if it is octal number than it should not have number `9` in it otherwise remove leading `0`. Suppose you remove leading `0`, now it will have value `902340`, which has `6` digits. But in your query statement you have written `WHERE substr(code_id, 3, 5) = '".$id`, which means you are checking for `5` characters in left side with `6` characters in right(`$id` has 6 digits). Which will never be satisfied. You need to correct those parts first I believe.

Answer (score 0):

you can't do algebra on alphabets, therefore you need to split the alphabets and the numerics like so:

```
$id = 0902340
$query = "SELECT substr(code_id,3,5) as cd  FROM tb_inv WHERE substr(code_id,3,5) =  '".$id."' ORDER BY code_id DESC LIMIT 1";
$get_id =  $this->db->query($query);
$show_id = $get_id->num_rows();
$new_code = $get_id->row();

if($show_id > 0){
    $prefix = substr($new_code->cd, 0, 3); // get the prefix 3 chars at front
    $number = substr($new_code->cd, 3);  // get the remaining chars
    $new = $number + 1;  // add it with 1, php automatically convert strings that can be converted to numbers
    $fix_code = $prefix . substr("00000" . $number, -5); // re-assemble the code
}else{
    $fix_code = 'CO-00001';
}
```

Comment: thanks @am05mhz, how if its value has reached a thousand whether to keep using `substr ("00000". $ number, -5);`

Comment: 1000 still below 5 digits, its ok, if its 6 digits or more, then just add the `0` and change the -5 to how many digits you need

Answer (score 0):

you can split the id into two parts, the string one, and the digit one. then increment the digit part then re concat the two parts again

```
list($strPrefix, $digitPart) = split('-', $oldId);
$digitPart++;
$newCode = $strPrefix . '-' . $digitPart;
```

Comment: if it's automatically added number 1 at the end of the ang because I use 00001 usually only to read 1 zero it can not be written